# Broken Function need some assistance/advice

Tags: javascript, html

I can not seem to get this "myfunction1" to work. Maybe I have it set up wrong or a stupid mistake. I need it to work so if the two text inputs have nothing in them you receive a pop up alerting you to fix the form. If there is already an input in the boxs I need it to say completed or thank you. I am sure its an easy fix but if someone could help me out I would appreciate it. Been searching for 4 hours now and still stuck. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form id="myForm">
    First name: <input type="text" id="field1" name="fname"><br><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" id="field2" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
    function myFunction1() {
     var x = document.getElementById("field1").value;
     if (x == null || x == "") {
     alert("Please Fill In Form Correctly");
     } else {
     alert("Thank You for Submitting");
  }
 }
  </script>



  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: after the question update It is working fine right?

Comment: When you're stuck with javascript, remember, almost every browser has an interactive console, wich prints out  the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script>
  function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
    function myFunction1() {
     var x = document.getElementById("field1").value;
     if(x){
         if (x == "") 
         {
            alert("Please Fill In Form Correctly");
         } else {
            alert("Thank You for Submitting");
        }
     }



 }
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
   <form id="myForm">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="field1"><br><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="field2"><br><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
        <input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Submit form">
    </form>


  </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can not seem to get this "myfunction1" to work.

Multiple issues in the code

1. You need to use `document.getElementById` rather than just `getElementById`
2. Id that you are passing to the method doesn't exists in your markup. In fact none of your markup input fields have id.

Try this

```
 function myFunction1() 
 {
     var field1 = document.getElementById("field1").value.trim();
     var field2 = document.getElementById("field2").value.trim();
     if ( field1.length == 0 || field2.length == 0) 
     {
        alert("Please Fill In Form Correctly");
     } 
     else 
     {
        alert("Thank You for Submitting");
     }
 }
```

Comment: I Fixed that! I feel really stupid, been sitting at computer for 5 hours now working on other html code, just getting into javascript. Still a little confused on how i could make it look at both field1 and field2 and check independently if only one of them has no entree made. Would i just continue on with else if etc... or is their an easier way around it. Thanks so Much!

Answer (score 0):

try the below code . insert id for each form element since you are using geteletmentbyid .

```js
<script>
  function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
    function myFunction1() 
 {
     var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
 
     if (x == null || x == "") 
  {
     alert("Please Fill In Form Correctly");
     } else {
     alert("Thank You for Submitting");
  }
 }
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>



  </head>
  <body>
   <form id="myForm">
    First name: <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
    Last name: <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Submit form">
</form>
    
<!-- copy the javascript party here--->
    
    
 </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That may not be the answer to your actual problem. But here is a working jsFiddle that might help you to get further: https://jsfiddle.net/y8135trb/4/

```
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    First name:
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="fname">
    <br>
    <br> Last name:
    <input type="text" id="field2" name="lname">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Submit form">
  </form>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }

    function myFunction1() {
      var x = document.getElementById("field1").value;

      if (typeof x == 'undefined' || x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please Fill In Form Correctly");
      } else {
        alert("Thank You for Submitting");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```